# Parse an expression with non whitespace seperated operators

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I am currently working on a compiler. Recently, I stumbled upon an issue concerning the parsing of operators in an expression. Obviously I have not found this to be an issue in other languages, which makes me think that there most likely is a friendly solution to this issue that I have yet to think of.

An expression like `a = 32*-1` is an expression where the `*` and `-` are seperate operators, but the developer chose to combine them. A possibility is to force operator whitespace delimiting. However, I would rather not.

My current setup for operators allows for easy implementation of new operators. However, as for now, this makes operator lookup more expensive. I would like to keep my operators from having to follow any rules; no operator should have to be devised such that it is not possible to be parsed as an operator when written. What I mean by this is for example adding a rule like if an operator starts with a parenthesis it will be split there to handle an expressions like `a = (*ptr).member_value`. I do not want such a rule as it then imposes a limit on starting an operator with a parenthesis.

I have thought of doing something like finding the longest consecutive operator starting from the beginning that is a valid operator and then split there. I am wondering if this could be a valid solution and whether it may cause some problems. If there are any discussion about this topic or standard algorithms that would also be deeply appreciated.

Comment: When you mention adding new operators, are you talking about you as the language designer adding new operators or are you talking about user-defined operators (i.e. a user of your language can write something like `def -* ...` and now a `-*` operator exists)? In the latter case I would strongly recommend to require spaces between consecutive operators. Otherwise code like `32*-1` could be silently broken by a single import. In the former case, a normal lexer respecting the maximal munch rule will work just fine.

Comment: @sepp2k All operators are defined in the compiler but can, like C++, be overloaded to work for other combinations of types. I will check out the "maximal munch rule."

Comment: Overloading of existing operators is fine because it doesn't affect the question "should `a*-b` be parsed as two operators or a single `-*` operator". As long as the lexer knows which operators exist, there's no problem. The maximal munch rule is basically just what you said in your post: the longest match wins.

Answer (score 0):

As per sepp2k's recommendation, I tried using "maximal munch" aka "longest match" to solve this and it works great for now.

See more information about the topic on the short [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) page.